# How can I hide comment count in the wordpress loop only when there are no comments

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am showing the comment count in the wordpress loop in the `category.php`.

I would like to only show the count if it is not `0`.

I have tried a number of if statements but cannot find something that works to check comment count while in the loop and only show if it is not 0, or more than 0, or not empty...etc.

To print the comment count (in the loop) I am using -
`<?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?>`

I would like to wrap it in an if statement but

```
<?php if (comments_number() != 0 ) {...
```

(or `!= 'No Comments'` or `empty` or any number of other things I've tried!) doesn't work - in fact it seemed to print the comment number from within the if statement which I didn't think was possible but clearly I am missing some knowledge here that's having me get it wrong. I also tried:

```
<?php if (have_comments() != 0 ) {...
```

Can anyone help show me **what if statement would be required around my comment number print in order to hide it if there are 0/No Comments**. Thank you

Edit: I also tried changing the `'0'` to `''` in `comments_number` but as expected, that still prints the comment wrapper which I don't want as the wrapper is styled. I want it to not print anything at all if there are no comments.

Comment: `<?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' );` - there is no echo, print or similar here, so that clearly indicates that this function does not _return_ anything, but writes to the output buffer directly. So you can not use it in any constructs such as `if( functioncall() == "value"()` - you would have to wrap this function call into something that catches what it writes to the output buffer first of all.

Comment: But if you check the [code of that function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_number/#source), you see that it is actually just a wrapper, that itself calls `get_comments_number_text`, and then echos what _that_ function returns. So if you wanted to check the return value in any if statement or something like that, use `get_comments_number_text` for that instead.

Comment: Wondering whether all that is actually necessary though. The first function parameter is the text it is supposed to output, when no comments exist. So the first thing I would try here, is simply making that first parameter an _empty string_, instead of passing `'0'` …

Comment: Hi @cBroe thanks for those explanations - that's really useful - I didn't realise that was the case with this function (I'm still learning!). Re. the empty string, I edited the question to say that if I do that it still prints the wrapper and I need no markup to print at all when there are no comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the function get_comments_number_text() which returns text based on your current comment count.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number_text/

```
if(get_comments_number_text( '0', '1', '%' ) !== "0"){
   echo "comment";             
}
```

If you have a post_id you can also use the following:

```
$number = get_comments_number( $post_id );

if ( $number > 1 ) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the solution I was after.